# How to deal with a dataset that has multivalued column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, migration, normalization

I wanted to import a table that has 43 columns and one of the columns is 'tag' which has multi values separated by commas like below:

[image]

I know the right way is to create a new table that has a primary key and have the tags. for example for product x we have

```
x1, tag1
x1, tag2
x1, tag3
```

But the question is that how can I even do this in real word when I have thousands rows of data that each row has multi value tags? How to converted it to 1nf normalization and insert all that data?

Facts:

1. I am using SQL Server 2016 but I can try with MySQL as well.
2. The source data is Excel and I am going to import that data into a database (MySQL or SQL Server)

Thanks

Comment: so you just want to split the a single tags into multiple rows depending on the list in it?

Comment: What has your research shown you?

Comment: To be honest, if it was me, I'd probably approach it in two steps.  First, just get the raw data from Excel into a temp/staging table.  Secondly, have a routine in SQL that processes the staged data, row-by-row - that way, you know the context of each row when inserting the "tags" data (so the relationship is right).  There are various methods that can be used to transform a comma-delimited string into a table of rows

Comment: @Harry Yes, basically the first step is splitting them into multi rows (which will be normalized in 1nf) and then put them into new table (2nf)

Comment: slq server has the string_split function. once the data is in SQL you should be able to separate them out using this function

Comment: @Craig You are right, I think the routines would be helpful to split the multi valued rows into different rows and then insert them into new table then the dealing will be much easier. Can you please show me a real example that we can do ? Did you mean routines in SQL or use something like python?

Comment: @MajidRezaie err, google string_split?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from normalising the data etc, splitting the csv row is farily straight forward in Sql Server. 2016 has the string split function that you can take advantage of.

here is a sample code.

```
declare @tag varchar(50) = 'tag1,tag2,tag3'

select * from string_split(@tag,',') as split_tags
```

Comment: Thank you i will check this out today